# Is it possible to add the output of your command to a text file (not to overwrite the text file) in linux?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a command line like this:

```
awk  '$9 < 0.1' s_all_frq.txt | wc -l  
awk  '$9 >= 0.1 && $9 < 0.2 ' s_all_frq.txt | wc -l
```

when I run it I get an output like this.

```
$ awk  '$9 < 0.1' s_all_frq.txt | wc -l  
63278
$awk  '$9 >= 0.1 && $9 < 0.2 ' s_all_frq.txt | wc -l  
2346
```

when I try to save this in a text file it always replace the first output. so I use these commands:

```
awk  '$9 < 0.1' s_all_frq.txt | wc -l > 1.txt 

awk  '$9 >= 0.1 &&$9 < 0.2 ' s_all_frq.txt | wc -l > 1.txt
```

and I get only `2346` saved on the text file. which I assume that the file got overwritten. I wonder if it's possible to add something to this command to save the output as new line in the file so I will have this in the final file:

```
63278
2346
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `>>` instead of `>` to append instead of replace.

```
awk '$9 >= 0.1 &&$9 < 0.2 ' s_all_frq.txt | wc -l >> 1.txt
```

Other example:

```
user@home:~$ echo A >1.txt
user@home:~$ echo B >1.txt
user@home:~$ cat 1.txt
B
user@home:~$ echo C >>1.txt
user@home:~$ cat 1.txt
B
C
user@home:~$
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `>>` instead of `>`, e.g.

```
awk '$9 < 0.1' s_all_frq.txt | wc -l >> 1.txt

awk '$9 >= 0.1 &&$9 < 0.2 ' s_all_frq.txt | wc -l >> 1.txt
```

This will append the output to the file.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it all inside `awk`.

```
awk '$9 >= 0.1 && $9 < 0.2 {print | "wc -l > 1.txt"}' s_all_frq.txt
```

#### Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Redirection):

> **`print items > output-file`**
>
> This redirection prints the items into the output file named output-file. The file name output-file can be any expression. Its value is changed to a string and then used as a file name
>   When this type of redirection is used, the output-file is erased before the first output is written to it. **Subsequent writes to the same output-file do not erase output-file, but append to it. (This is different from how you use redirections in shell scripts.)** If output-file does not exist, it is created.
>
> For example, here is how an awk program can write a list of BBS names to one file named name-list, and a list of phone numbers to another file named phone-list:

```
      $ awk '{ print $2 > "phone-list"
      >        print $1 > "name-list" }' BBS-list
      $ cat phone-list
      -| 555-5553
      -| 555-3412
      ...
      $ cat name-list
      -| aardvark
      -| alpo-net
      ...
```

> Each output file contains one name or number per line.

#### Example:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/1/{print "this is one" > "newfile.txt"}' file.txt
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat newfile.txt 
this is one
this is one
```

Comment: the downvote is not by me, but I guess your awk line would overwrite the existing data in 1.txt. right?

Comment: in your script, you used print "|" not ">".

Comment: Hi @Kent it was my understanding that as long as he has both syntaxes in one awk one-liner, the content of the output will get appended to the file as awk looks at `>` differently than `bash`.

Comment: your ">"  belongs to the "command" not awk context. you could do a simple test. prepare a file (1.txt), with one line, say 100. then `echo "xyz"|awk '{print | "wc -l > 1.txt"}'` then check the content of 1.txt, see if 100 is still there.

Comment: @Kent True that I agree. May be I am understanding it in a different context. I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

one awk process without 'wc' should work

```
awk '$9<0.1{i++;next;} $9<0.2{j++} END{print i;print j}' s_all_frq.txt
```

**not tested**